# how to get mouseover to draw on html canvas with event listener with my code? https://jsfiddle.net/dannixx/d0p0j8cL/

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

how to get mouseover to draw on html canvas with event listener with my code? https://jsfiddle.net/dannixx/d0p0j8cL/
jifiddle file, i want to be able to draw line on canvas with mouseover  https://jsfiddle.net/dannixx/d0p0j8cL/

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Canvas</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #Canvas1 {

        border: : dotted 3px black;
        background-color: blue;    


        }

    </style>

    <script>

       window.onload = function(){

           var theCanvas = document.getElementById("Canvas1");

    if (theCanvas && document.getContext("2d")){
     var ctx = theCanvas.getContext("2d";)
     if(ctx){
         ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
         ctx.fillRect(0,0 ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)


     }


       } 
    }




    </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>cnavas</h1>
    <p>ex</p>
    <canvas id="Canvas1" width="400", height="300"></canvas>





<p id="demo"></p>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a really simple example using a onmousemove listener that updates the new mouse coordinates and draws a line from the previous coordinates to the new coordinates. Run it and see!

```js
   var x = null;
   var y = null;
   var c = null;
   var ctx = null;


function getPos(e) {
         //if it is the first time the event listener is called then set x and y to the new mouse coordinate
         if(x == null) {
             x=e.clientX;
             y=e.clientY;
           }
         //otherwise draw from the previous point (x, y) to the new coordinates (e.clientX, e.clientY).

         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x,y);
         ctx.lineTo(e.clientX,e.clientY);
         ctx.stroke();
         x=e.clientX;
         y=e.clientY;
     }
     
 
      window.onload = function(){
       c=document.getElementById("Canvas1");
       ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    }
```

```html
<canvas onmousemove="getPos(event)" id="Canvas1" width="400", height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: your code doesn't contain any draw line function so it's difficult to say what you did wrong. All your code does is draw the canvas. Can you explain to me specifically what you don't understand? To implement this solution all you have to do is add the event listener to your canvas element and add what I  wrote.

Comment: this my code https://jsfiddle.net/dannixx/5oh3mv0m/, can you make it show a black line is drawn when mouse goes over the box, thanks

Comment: its work thank you, i have something to hand in for my school assignment tommorrow

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example script (using the stroke method) for drawing on a canvas:

HTML :

```
<canvas id="can1"></canvas>
```

CSS :

```
#can1 {
    border:dashed 3px #000;
}
```

JavaScript :

```
var can = document.getElementById("can1");
var canCtx = can.getContext("2d");
var sx = 0, sy = 0;
var clicked = false;
function _left(e){
    return e.pageX - can.offsetLeft;
}
function _top(e){
    return e.pageY - can.offsetTop;
}
function _draw(e, sx, sy){
    var x = _left(e);
    var y = _top(e);
    canCtx.moveTo(sx, sy);
    canCtx.lineTo(x, y);
    canCtx.strokeStyle="red";
    canCtx.stroke();
}
can.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    sx = _left(e);
    sy = _top(e);
    _draw(e, sx, sy);
    clicked = true;
}, false);
can.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    if(clicked == true){
        _draw(e, can);
    }
}, false);
addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    clicked = false;
}, false);
```

Comment: i cant get it to draw a line when it goes over the canvas, can you show me what i did wrong? this is my code https://jsfiddle.net/dannixx/84oaqcj5/